# Cannot see new SQL tables in Django online interface on PythonAnywhere

Tags: mysql, django, pythonanywhere

As part of hosting my website I have an SQL server on pythonanywhere.com with some data collected from my website. I need to aggregate some of the information into a new table stored in the same database. If I use the code below I can create a new table as observed by the `SHOW TABLES` query. However, I cannot see that table in the Django online interface provided alongside the SQL server.

Why is that the case? How can I make the new visible on the Django interface so I can browse the content and modify it?

```
from __future__ import print_function

from mysql.connector import connect as sql_connect
import sshtunnel
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
from copy import deepcopy

sshtunnel.SSH_TIMEOUT = 5.0
sshtunnel.TUNNEL_TIMEOUT = 5.0


def try_query(query):
    try:
        cursor.execute(query)
        connection.commit()
    except Exception:
        connection.rollback()
        raise


if __name__ == '__main__':
    remote_bind_address = ('{}.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com'.format(SSH_USERNAME), 3306)
    tunnel = SSHTunnelForwarder(('ssh.pythonanywhere.com'),
                                ssh_username=SSH_USERNAME, ssh_password=SSH_PASSWORD,
                                remote_bind_address=remote_bind_address)
    tunnel.start()
    connection = sql_connect(user=SSH_USERNAME, password=DATABASE_PASSWORD,
                             host='127.0.0.1', port=tunnel.local_bind_port,
                             database=DATABASE_NAME)

    print("Connection successful!")
    cursor = connection.cursor()                      # get the cursor
    cursor.execute("USE {}".format(DATABASE_NAME))    # select the database

    cursor.execute("SHOW TABLES")
    prev_tables = deepcopy(cursor.fetchall())

    try_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestTable(TestName VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY, SupplInfo VARCHAR(255))")
    print("Created table.")
    cursor.execute("SHOW TABLES")
    new_tables = deepcopy(cursor.fetchall())
```

Comment: Django doesn't care about tables, it cares about models. Have you created a model for this? (And in any case, you should create the model *first* and then let Django create the model via a migration.)

Comment: Oh, okay. I'm not the developer that designed the Django models, but an analyst that's using the data from the website. I've never used Django. I would like to join some tables together and store them on the SQL server (they would not be populated automatically). Would it be very bad practice to add tables to the underlying SQL database used by Django without adding Django models? Of course, I would not be able to use the online interface, but that would be okay then.

Comment: No, if you don't need Django to be involved you can create whatever tables you like.